# PHP CLI get *raw* commandline

Tags: php, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to get the *exact* raw command line in PHP as typed in?

`$ ./example.php --key1="value" --key2='value' --key3=  value-with-leading-double-blank`

I'd like to now if *value* was enclosed in single or double quotes and if any blanks were typed. Obviously `implode(' ', $argv[])` does not work as surrounding quotes and blanks have been stripped already.

Any hints?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Why do you care what kind of quotes were used?

Comment: What you get with the above is: `array(5) {   [0]=>   string(19) "example.php"   [1]=>   string(12) "--key1=value"   [2]=>   string(14) "--key2='value'"   [3]=>   string(7) "--key3="   [4]=>   string(31) "value-with-leading-double-blank" }`. As you can see, your key1 double quotes disappear, key2 still has single quotes intact, and the final value is not understood as belonging to key3. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Not even with `ps aux` you can get the quotes and double quotes, as they are interpreted. Why do you need this, please share your use case so maybe we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Trying to build a a more tolerant command line parser that allows `--key=value` as well as `--key value` and `--key my name is "john"` or even --key= = equal sign given`. Basically: "anything between = and next dash is the value". Blanks and quotes matter here.

Comment: No. The strings that you use to launch the program are first parsed by _the shell_ [eg: bash] and then passed to a kernel call to actually invoke the executable. If you want quotes, spaces, or metacharacters to survive through into the program you're invoking, then you will need to properly quote and/or escape them for your shell.